# how graphql tools addSchemaLevelResolver function works

Tags: graphql, graphql-tools

As I understood addSchemaLevelResolver function add a root level resolver on schema and cut off the all other resolvers. And I tried that method like in the below.

```
if (process.env.DEV === true) {
  schema = addSchemaLevelResolver(schema, () => {
    throw new Error("Internal Server Error!");
  });
}
```

Yes this function resolving and throw error when first call on some query or mutation on the schema. But after that it's not throwing the error as I expected and not blocking resolvers in the schema. Is this function only work for first call or is that a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addSchemaLevelResolver` has been [removed](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/releases/tag/%40graphql-tools%2Fschema%408.0.0) in favor of [Resolvers Composition](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/resolvers-composition).
I believe `addSchemaLevelResolver` and the new `Resolvers Composition` would literally traverse the schema and add resolve function to each Type and Field.